# Table of Contents - Undefined control sequence

Tags: biblatex, table-of-contents, abnt

I'm having problem to compile a document with a table of contents.

I have made some debug process that I show here:

Here is my debug code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,openright,twoside,a4paper,english,french,spanish,brazil]{abntex2}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%\usepackage[brazilian,hyperpageref]{backref}   
%\usepackage[num]{abntex2cite}
\usepackage[language=brazil,style=abnt-numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{/home/joaodelsolar/ArqPessoal/Mega/Profissional/Pesquisa/BancoDados/biblioteca.bib}


\begin{document}


\pdfbookmark[0]{\contentsname}{toc}
\tableofcontents*
\cleardoublepage

test

\cite{Aulete2016}

\printbibliography
%\bibliography{/home/joaodelsolar/ArqPessoal/Mega/Profissional/Pesquisa/BancoDados/biblioteca}

\begin{anexosenv}

\partanexos

test-anex

\end{anexosenv}

\end{document}
```

1. When I use the cite package `abtex2cite`, it compile without problem:
2. When using biblatex, I remove the command `\tableofcontents*`, it compile without problem.
3. When using `biblatex`, I remove the environment `anexosenv`,  it compiles without problem.
4. With I use the command `\tableofcontents*` and biblatex, with the environment 'anexosenv' present, I receive the error:

> *Undefined control sequence. ...{part}{\uppercase {Anexos}}{7}{section*.3}*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an error on Abntex2.

Including [\usepackage{relsize}](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/abntex2/wcemusyijU0) solve the problem.

There is an open [issue on github](https://github.com/abntex/abntex2/issues/180).